# Stuck using array.splice() to shuffle a deck array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to randomly shuffle a deck array of `Card` objects into a `newDeck` array of `Card` objects using `array.splice()`.  I imagine my problem is either something to do with variable scope, or a misapprehension about `array.splice()`.

```
var deck = [new Card(), new Card(), new Card(), new Card(), new Card(), new Card()];
var newDeck = [];
var shuffle = function(){
    var i = "";
    for (i = 0; i < deck.length; i++){      
        newDeck[i] = deck.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length, 1));
}    
};

shuffle();
```

Is there a better way to shuffle a deck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a misapprehension about `array.splice()`. Read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice): It will return an array of the removed elements, in your case with one card: `[<object Card>]`. Also, with `deck.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length, 1))`, the `1` (which i guess should be how many cards to remove) is an argument to `Math.floor`, not `splice` - you will remove all elements after the index. So, you seem to want:

```
function shuffle(deck) {
    var newDeck = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < deck.length; i++)    
        newDeck[i] = deck.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length), 1)[0];
    return newDeck;
}    
shuffle([new Card(), new Card(), new Card(), new Card(), new Card(), new Card()]);
```

You have asked for other ways to shuffle: You could use the very common

```
deck.sort(function(a, b){ return 0.5-Math.random(); })
```

or the algorithm from [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#shuffle):

```
function shuffle(deck) {
    var newDeck = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {    
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));  
        newDeck[i] = newDeck[rand];
        newDeck[rand] = deck[i];
    }
    return newDeck;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Bergi!  I was wondering what array.splice would return. Seems to work now, but I might try those other ways too.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse your `for` cycle:

```
for (i = deck.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    newDeck.push(deck.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length))[0]);
```

The problem you're having is that `deck.length` decreases every time the cycle executes `deck.splice`. Alternatively, you can save `deck.length` in a separate variable before running the script:

```
var length = deck.length;
for (i = 0; i < length; i++){      
    newDeck[i] = deck.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length))[0];
```

Inside the cycle, though, you have to use `deck.length`.

Note: `Math.floor` takes just one argument. What was that ", 1" supposed to be? And initializing `i = ""` is pointless, since that value is unused. Just put `var i;`.

**Edit**: fixed a missing point about the return value of `Array.splice`.

Comment: Thanks, MaxArt.  The ",1" was supposed to be an argument of the splice function, my bad.  Good tip for putting deck,length in a separate variable. Bergi, below, pointed out that array.splice returns an array containing the elements selected, an dnot simply a value...

Answer (score 0):

You could as well use the `Array#shuffle` method from [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#shuffle) in case you do not want to reinvent the wheel in that case ;)