# Why doesn't splicing an object from an array in Javascript return the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects (say, a deck of cards):

```
var deck = [];
deck.push(new Card(suit, rank));
```

The following seems to work:

```
var card = deck.pop();
var card = deck.shift();
```

(pulling from the "top" or "bottom" of the deck respectively)

But if I want a card from the middle (say, if this was a hand of cards)

```
var card = deck.splice(2,1);
```

The object doesn't seem to get properly assigned to the variable (everything is undefined). Everything I look up says that splice should return the object that I'm removing - what am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
var card = deck.splice(2,1)[0];
```

Since splice returns an **array** of the removed elements...

Answer (score 0):

[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns an array of possible removed elements, so if you remove only one element you still have an array. So:

```
var card = deck.splice(2, 1)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) should return an array containing the element you removed. The actual element can be obtained like:

```
var card = deck.splice(2,1)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just the same error as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10719185/1048572) (even a quite similiar environment :-): [`.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns an *Array* of the removed elements, not a single element. So you will need to get the first element of that array:

```
var card = deck.splice(2,1)[0];
```